# Variation on Adding HTML Attributes to Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need a form on my ASP.NET MVC Razor page. My preference would be to use the following syntax:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
}
```

However, I need several attributes added to the form. So I ended up with something like the following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "value" }))
{
}
```

However, this has an undesired side effect. If there are query arguments in this page's request, the first form passes them along when the form is submitted. However, the second version does not.

I really don't know why `BeginForm()` doesn't support attributes, but is there a straight-forward way to add attributes to `BeginForm()` and still pass along any query arguments when the for is submitted?

**EDIT:**

After looking into this, it would seem the best solution is something like this:

```
<form action="@Request.RawUrl" method="post" name="value">
</form>
```

However, when using this syntax, client-side validation is disabled. It seems there is no good solution to this situation without more complicated and potentially unreliable constructs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed true, but I would go with a custom helper in order to preserve the form context inside which is used for client side validation:

```
public static class FormExtensions
{
    private static object _lastFormNumKey = new object();

    public static IDisposable BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string rawUrl = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        return htmlHelper.FormHelper(rawUrl, FormMethod.Post, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    }

    private static int IncrementFormCount(IDictionary items)
    {
        object obj2 = items[_lastFormNumKey];
        int num = (obj2 != null) ? (((int)obj2) + 1) : 0;
        items[_lastFormNumKey] = num;
        return num;
    }

    private static string DefaultFormIdGenerator(this HtmlHelper htmlhelper)
    {
        int num = IncrementFormCount(htmlhelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items);
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "form{0}", new object[] { num });
    }

    private static IDisposable FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("form");
        builder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes);
        builder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
        builder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);
        bool flag = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;
        if (flag)
        {
            builder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.DefaultFormIdGenerator());
        }
        htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        var form = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
        if (flag)
        {
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = builder.Attributes["id"];
        }
        return form;
    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { name = "value" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin. Could you describe a little about what `IncrementFormCount`, `DefaultFormIdGenerator`, and `FormHelper` do?

Comment: @JonathanWood, the FormHelper generates the `<form>` element using TagBuilders. The `DefaultFormIdGenerator` basically tracks the number of forms rendered in the given view by storing their count in the HttpContext and incrementing it everytime. It basically allows you to have form ids like form0, form1, form2, ... which is used by the unobtrusive client side validation.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work. However, I had to modify the usage to `@using (Html.BeginForm(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-horizontal" })))` to avoid ambiguity with the version of `BeginForm()` that accepts just route values.

Comment: @JonathanWood, no this wouldn't solve your problem because there's also a BeginForm overload that takes a RouteValueDictionary which represent routeValues and not htmlAttributes. So you won't get the name html attribute on your form if you do that. I have updated my answer to illustrate how to overcome this issue using named parameters: `@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new { name = "value" }))`

Comment: I see. `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes()` also returns type `RouteValueDictionary`. Well that's odd. The code I posted compiled without any complaint. But your version is a bit more compact.

Comment: @JonathanWood, your code compiled without complaint but at runtime I guess it didn't call the correct overload.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here is quick solution (it works with MVC4).

Declare the extension method:

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper helper, object htmlAttributes)
{
        return helper.BeginForm(helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"].ToString(),
                                helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"].ToString(), 
                                FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes);
}
```

and use it in your page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(htmlAttributes: new {@class="form-horizontal"})) 
{
...
}
```

Comment: I lose all my querystrings using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Small modification to source code:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/FormExtensions.cs

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, object htmlAttributes)
{
   // generates <form action="{current url}" method="post">...</form>
   string formAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
   return FormHelper(htmlHelper, formAction, FormMethod.Post, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
}

private static MvcForm FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
{
   TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
   tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
   // action is implicitly generated, so htmlAttributes take precedence.
   tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
   // method is an explicit parameter, so it takes precedence over the htmlAttributes.
   tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);

   bool traditionalJavascriptEnabled = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ClientValidationEnabled
                                       && !htmlHelper.ViewContext.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled;

   if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
   {
       // forms must have an ID for client validation
       tagBuilder.GenerateId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormIdGenerator());
   }

   htmlHelper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
   MvcForm theForm = new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext);

   if (traditionalJavascriptEnabled)
   {
       htmlHelper.ViewContext.FormContext.FormId = tagBuilder.Attributes["id"];
   }

   return theForm;
}
```

Comment: `ViewContext.FormIdGenerator()` is internal.  :-(